# Send post from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in Asp.Net, I trying to do a post from view to controller like:

```
@model Models.CapturaViewModel
  @using(Html.BeginForm("EnviarIncrementos", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "table-bordered" }))
 {
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Fecha de movimiento:
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-3">
      <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-xs" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

As you can see I have a date picker there. I want to know how can I receive value from that date picker in controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnviarIncrementos()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Help is very appreciatted. Regards

Comment: Where's your `POST` actionresult? and I don't see any Model being passed to razor view.

Comment: I added model and [HttpPost] to controller method, now If I clck on submit button method  of controller is actioned correctly, but I don't know how to pass datepicker value to method @12seconds

Comment: your input tag doesn't have a name attribute and a name attribute and modify your controller method to take a DateTime parameter where the name of the input matches the name of the controller method parameter.  you also have the datepickerid on the div and not the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.cshtml` for input require a `name` attribute to pass the data to your Controller via POST.

Don't know what property `CapturaViewModel` have but lets assume you have a property `public DateTime DatePicker { get; set; }`

With that, now you need to modify your `.cshtml` where

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" />
```

to

```
<input type='text' name="DatePicker" class="form-control" />
```

or via using `HtmlHelper`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePicker, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Lastly your controller is missing parameter that accepts `CapturaViewModel`. Change your controller to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnviarIncrementos(CapturaViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: but my viewmodel need to have property `public Datetime DatePicker {get; set;}` right?

Comment: Yes, I did mention that. It doesn't have to be called `DatePicker`, that is up to you. You just need to make sure the name matches between your property you defined in your viewmodel and the `name` attribute if you are not using HtmlHelper